# Is what my dentist is doing legal?

Tags: fraud

I recently got dental work done and after he finished, my dentist had me pay a bit extra for an additional bit of work that 'went over my coverage amount' and gave me an itemized statement/receipt showing each charge and the extra I paid. It also showed the amount that was supposedly being submitted to my insurance company. (It's a Medicare Advantage dental plan) When I logged onto my insurance website a few days later I see he padded the charges substantially when submitting the bill to them, going way over my insurance amount. Also, he submitted codes requesting payment for work he didn't do. Is that legal? Should I mention it to my insurance company?

Comment: Here we don't give advice as to what people _should_ do (other than hire a lawyer). You may want to rephrase your question to avoid being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is normal** for in-network providers. If you take the time to look at the insurance company's explanation of benefits, you'll find it happens with all providers.

Insurance companies have negotiated rates with each in-network provider. Their contracts may allow or prohibit certain billing items, for example a blood draw fee may already be included with a lab test fee.

Rates and billing policies vary across each insurance contract, so the provider bills the insurance company with the maximum rate, which you saw. The insurance company will process the claim, reducing billed fees to the contractual rates and adjusting items as necessary. You will get an explanation of benefits detailing the adjustment and the *allowed amount* which will be much more reasonable.

Billed rates practically don't serve any purpose, save to come up with some huge "savings" number on your insurance statement. Even uninsured cash payers will receive a lower cash rate, in line with insurance rates.

With modern billing software and insurance company Internet APIs, the doctor's office knows what they're going to be paid in advance, which is the number that was shared with you. Your provider either extended the negotiated rates to the non-covered work or gave you an uninsured discounted price.

Comment: Why on Earth would an insurance company agree to pay more than an uninsured patient would have to?

Comment: @Greendrake because insurance companies’ products are legally limited to a percentage of benefits paid out, essentially.

Comment: @Greendrake Insurance claims impose additional costs. For an insured patient, the provider has to code the services done, file a claim, wait a month or so while it's processed and paid, if there's a mistake or dispute, go through adjustment processes, plus the overhead of negotiating rates and contracts, and now insurers are requiring metrics and patient surveys. One provider overcharged my copay, so I got a check in the mail, another attributed my flu shot to a uncovered doctor, so it was free. A cash patient simply receives a cost and is usually required to pay in advance of the services.

Comment: The costs of running insurance business explain why it would rather pay out **less**, not more than the provider would bill an uninsured patient. It still doesn't make any sense why they would do the opposite.

Comment: @Greendrake In the US, it is not mandatory a provider accept insurance, nor any specific insurer or their network. If an insurer doesn't adequately compensate, the provider will simply drop that network, and subscribers will leave. My employer offers 5 different plans, I'll just choose a better one. You also have to consider that 2/3 of employer health plans are self-insured by the employer, the health plan merely passes along the bill with a markup. Quality of health plans is a major factor in hiring and employee retention, so if a company is stingy with their coverage, employees will quit.

Comment: @Greendrake The system places choice largely in the hands of the consumer, especially since employers are paying 80% of the costs on average. This applies to government benefits as well, OP is on Medicare Advantage, which means the government is paying a fixed amount to a private insurer to provide elderly health benefits, instead of acting as the insurer themselves. If OP doesn't like the coverage, they are free to switch to some other MA plan.

Comment: I would differ a bit - while padding charges (submitting VERY large charges) is normal practice, and one expects to see an explanation of benefits (EOB) with a much lower dollar amount allowed, it is NOT normal or legal for the provider to charge for services NOT rendered. That is fraud.  However, keep in mind that sometimes medical laypersons may not understand that two things are equivalent, and one is an allowed charge/procedure. For example, some dental providers ONLY provided ceramic fillings, but some insurers only covered amalgam (mercury) fillings, calling ceramic cosmetic enhancement.